# Uncaught TypeError: $thirdColumnCells.each is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am running this but I have the console keeps giving me the error in the question title. basically I am reading the `href` value from a link and I am pushing it into a `<ul>`

HTML

```
<div id="link"><ul></ul></div>
```

JQUERY

```
var $thirdColumnCells = $hiddenContentB.find('table.wikitable tr').find('td:nth-child(3) a').attr("href");

$thirdColumnCells.each(function(idx, cell) {
   var valB = $(cell).text().match(/\d+/)[0];
   valuesB.push($(cell).html());
   $('#link').append('<li>'+ valB + '</li>');
});
```

Comment: `$thirdColumnCells` is a string....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `.attr()` returns a string.

jQuery's `.each()` iterates over objects and arrays, usually array-like objects holding elements

What you're doing is

```
var $thirdColumnCells = $(element).attr("href");

$thirdColumnCells.each(... // <- that's a string !!!
```